# ITagAggregator<T>.TagsChanged is never fired

Tags: c#, mef

I have fairly simple TagProvider which I want to consume by my custom adornment. It works all well except hooking on TagsChange event.

Here is the code which I am using to get the tag service factory:

```
[Import]
internal IViewTagAggregatorFactoryService AggregatorService = null;

...    

MyTagAggregator = AggregatorService.CreateTagAggregator<MyTag>(View); 
MyTagAggregator.TagsChanged += MyTagAggregator_TagsChanged;
```

But MyTagAggregator_TagsChanged delegate is never fired. I tried with different types of tags, some are custom and some are built-in (for instance SmartTag).

Am I missing something, should I set something else before I can consume this event?

Comment: could you please add to your description a peace of code where you instanciate your AggregatorService

Comment: It is already there. AggregatorService is initialized by VS services [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.tagging.iviewtagaggregatorfactoryservice.aspx). It is not problem with initialization, CreateTagAggregator method is working, I am getting the reference to MyTagAggregator, also setting the delegate works, but the event is never fired. In most examples which I saw, this is should be suffice.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I've located the problem.

AggregatorService.CreateTagAggregator method will call IViewTaggerProvider.CreateTagger method. In my case implementation was something like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IViewTaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]    
[TagType(typeof(MyTag))]
internal class MyTaggerProvider : IViewTaggerProvider
{
    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        return new MyTagger(this) as ITagger<T>;
    }
}
```

This returned always the new instance of TagAggregator. So when I changed something on one instance, it was, naturally, not affected on others. Solution for this is to leverage the Properties property on TextView, so every subsequent call will return the same instance for particular TextView:

```
[Export(typeof(IViewTaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]    
[TagType(typeof(MyTag))]
internal class MyTaggerProvider : IViewTaggerProvider
{
    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        return TextView.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(delegate() { return new MyTagger(this); }) as ITagger<T>;
    }
}
```